# module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'GraphKeys'

Tags: tensorflow2.0

`enter code here`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Twn1S.png)I have tensorflow-gpu 2.0.0,and the question is AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'GraphKeys'.this project is run at tensorflow==1.15rc2.what should i do?

Comment: Could you provide a lot more detail to your question?  Perhaps include the code, the inputs to the code, the expected output, and the actual output?  As your question is, any answers would just be guessing at your issue.

Comment: when i use tensorflow-gpu 2.0 ,:[link](Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_100.dll)and tf.test.is_gpu_available()  output is true ,but when i use tensorflow 1.15  it shows tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_100.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_100.dll not found. and the output is false

Comment: when i change the cuda version to 10.0 all the problem was gone